# iPad : CATransform3DMakeRotation flipping issue: half of the view is not visible

Tags: iphone, transition

I have written some code to rotate a imageview 90 degrees and then flip it.  However the flip seems to cut off half the image.  Why does this happen?

```
UIImageView *tempView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:button.frame];
    tempView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"propertyCard.png"];
    //tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    tempView.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:tempView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1
                          delay: 0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         // rotate
                         tempView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI /2, 0., 0, 1);                        
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [self showPropertyViews];

                         [UIView animateWithDuration: 1 
                                               delay: 0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                          animations:^{

                                              // flip
                                              tempView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0,1.0,0.0);

                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                                              [UIView animateWithDuration: 1
                                                                    delay: 0
                                                                  options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                                               animations:^{

                                                                  tempView.frame = CGRectMake(propertyView.frame.origin.y + 12, propertyView.frame.origin.x +12, propertyView.frame.size.height-20, propertyView.frame.size.width-20);
                                                                  tempView.center = propertyView.center;
                                                               }
                                                               completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                                                   tempView.hidden = YES;
                                                                   propertyView.hidden = NO;
                                                                   propertyView.alpha = 1;
                                                                   [self displayCoverFlow];

                                                                   [tempView removeFromSuperview];
                                                                   [tempView release];



                                                               }];
                                              }];

                     }];
```

Comment: please edit your post and re-past the code - use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0 + 5, 0 +5, propertyView.frame.size.height-10, propertyView.frame.size.width-10);
                                                              tempView.center = propertyView.center;
here you are changing frame . please print your imageView object before and after animation and see what is the difference betweeen both.

Answer (score 8):

When your view is turned nearly perpendicular to the screen, the more distant half will be covered by some of your other view in the view hierarchy. Try to set some "enough big" Z value for the view being animated, for example:

```
myView.layer.zPosition = 1000.0;
```

Comment: You just ended 3 hours of misery for me with this answer. Thanks!

Comment: You don't know how awesome you are!

Comment: I don know why -1000.0(negative value) worked for me